# Offline behavior of AWS SNS

Tags: ios, iphone

When device is offline or not in network, then after getting network access it should receive all the undelivered notification messages. Is SNS taking care of this scenario or it depends on GCM/APNS/WNS services?

Answer (score 0):

The SNS service uses its connections with GCM/APNS/WNS etc, to send push notifications to the mobile devices. It requires credentials from "Push notification Service Providers" in order to send the notification. **The notifications are kept in a queue for certain period of time, and it is not guaranteed to be delivered if the SNS service fails to establish the communication with GCM/APNS/WNS.**

[image]

Have a look at [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMobilePush.html) to know more about working of SNS.